# set a loop to use a function in r

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe with three columns and I would like to calculate 95% Upper tolerance levels for each variable in media. Here is how the data looks like:
So, for plastic and water I need to calculate tolerance levels separately for each variable and write it as 4th column. I am using

```
nptol.int(data$result, alpha = 0.05, P = 0.95, side = 1, method=c("WILKS"))
```

function.

```
media   variable    result
plastic A   2.3
plastic B   4
plastic C   4.6
plastic D   3
plastic A   2
plastic B   5
plastic C   6.7
plastic A   8
plastic B   5
plastic C   4
water   A   2
water   B   4
water   C   5
water   A   8.2
water   B   4
water   C   5
plastic A   6
plastic B   7
plastic C   11.2
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tolerance)
df %>% group_by(media, variable) %>% summarize(Upper = nptol.int(result, alpha = 0.05, P = 0.95, side = 1, method=c("WILKS"))$`1-sided.upper`)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   media [2]
  media   variable Upper
  <fct>   <fct>    <dbl>
1 plastic A         11.2
2 plastic B          8  
3 plastic C          7  
4 water   A          5  
5 water   B          8.2
6 water   C          4
```

If you want to write as a 4th column and keep all results, you can do:

```r
df %>% group_by(media, variable) %>% mutate(Upper = nptol.int(result, alpha = 0.05, P = 0.95, side = 1, method=c("WILKS"))$`1-sided.upper`)

# A tibble: 19 x 4
# Groups:   media, variable [6]
   media   variable result Upper
   <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 plastic A           2.3  11.2
 2 plastic B           4     8  
 3 plastic C           4.6   7  
 4 plastic A           3    11.2
 5 plastic B           2     8  
 6 plastic C           5     7  
 7 plastic A           6.7  11.2
 8 plastic B           8     8  
 9 plastic C           5     7  
10 plastic A           4    11.2
11 water   B           2     8.2
12 water   C           4     4  
13 water   A           5     5  
14 water   B           8.2   8.2
15 water   C           4     4  
16 water   A           5     5  
17 plastic B           6     8  
18 plastic C           7     7  
19 plastic A          11.2  11.2
```

**Data**
Your data has only a single D value and apparently it was an issue for `npol.int`, so I used this data instead:

```r
df = data.frame(media = c(rep("plastic",10), rep("water",6), rep("plastic",3)),
                variable = c(LETTERS[1:3],rep(LETTERS[1:3],5),"A"),
                result = c(2.3,4,4.6,3,2,5,6.7,8,5,4,2,4,5,8.2,4,5,6,7,11.2))
```

Comment: Glad that it helps you.